# cx_Oracle How to Pass a Composite/Complex array to a PLSQL Procedure?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

From this [guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/prez-stored-proc-084100.html) I am able to pass an associative array of a simple data type (like `cx_Oracle.NUMBER`) to a PL/SQL procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test
IS
    TYPE t_ids IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE foo(p_ids_i IN t_ids);
END;
/
```

To call it:

```
ids = cursor.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.NUMBER, [1,2,3])
cursor.callproc('test.foo', [ids])
```

---

However, I want to call the following procedure `foo` instead which takes a complex type instead.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test
IS
    TYPE r_foo IS RECORD (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(10));
    TYPE t_complex IS TABLE OF r_foo INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE foo(p_ids_i IN t_complex);
END;
/
```

I've tried various things like:

```
# Raises NotSupportedError: Variable_TypeByPythonType(): unhandled data type
foos = cursor.arrayvar((cx_Oracle.NUMBER, cx_Oracle.STRING), [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')])

# Raises NotSupportedError: Variable_MakeArray(): type does not support arrays
foos = cur.arrayvar(cx_Oracle.OBJECT, [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')])
```

---

The following is failing:

```
# Raises DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object TEST.R_FOO does not exist
record_type = conn.gettype('TEST.R_FOO')
```

It looks like you can create a type outside of a package and reference that.

```
CREATE TYPE t_foo IS TABLE OF NUMBER; -- Not an Associative Array
```

To reference it:

```
t = conn.gettype('T_FOO')
```

However, you are not allowed to create a RECORD of an Associative Array outside of a package. I could replace the RECORD with an Object, but I can't think of anything to replace the Associative Array with, which is the only collection type that cx_Oracle can pass in or out.

---

Full code:

PL/SQL:

```
-- returns 12.1.0.2.0
SELECT VERSION FROM v$instance;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE test
IS
    TYPE r_foo IS RECORD (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(10));
    TYPE t_complex IS TABLE OF r_foo INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
    PROCEDURE foo(p_ids_i IN t_complex);
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY test
IS
    PROCEDURE foo(p_ids_i IN t_complex)
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR i IN p_ids_i.FIRST .. p_ids_i.LAST LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_ids_i(i).id || ' ' || p_ids_i(i).name);
        END LOOP;
    END;
END;
/

-- The following works as expected.
DECLARE
    l_complex test.t_complex;
BEGIN
    l_complex(1).id := 1;
    l_complex(1).name := 'Matthew';

    l_complex(2).id := 2;
    l_complex(2).name := 'Moisen';

    test.foo(l_complex);
END;
```

Python:

```
import cx_Oracle

print cx_Oracle.version  # 5.3
print cx_Oracle.clientversion() # (12, 1, 0, 2, 0)

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@sid')
cur = conn.cursor()

result = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user_source WHERE name = 'TEST' and type = 'PACKAGE'")

# This prints the package spec successfully
for row in result:
    print row

# Raises DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object TEST.R_FOO does not exist
conn.gettype('TEST.R_FOO')

# Raises DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object TEST.T_COMPLEX does not exist
conn.gettype('TEST.T_COMPLEX')

# This raises the appropriate exception saying I called the procedure
# incorrectly, demonstrating that I have access to it.
cur.callproc('TEST.FOO', [])
```

---

After reinstalling cx_Oracle with $ORACLE_HOME and etc set to my 12c client, I was able to get a bit futher, but still hit an error with the `append` operation.

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@sid')

# This no longer raises an error
recordTypeObj = conn.gettype('TEST.R_FOO')
tableTypeObj = conn.gettype('TEST.T_COMPLEX')
rec = recordTypeObj.newobject()
tab = tableTypeObj.newobject()

# This works fine
rec.ID = 1
rec.NAME = "foo"

# This fails with 
# cx_Oracle.NotSupportedError: Object_ConvertFromPython(): unhandled data type 250
tab.append(rec)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is supported in cx_Oracle 5.3 and higher. You have to use the "object" syntax which supports this sort of thing.

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("cx_Oracle/dev@localhost/orcl")
recordTypeObj = conn.gettype("TEST.R_FOO")
tableTypeObj = conn.gettype("TEST.T_COMPLEX")

tab = tableTypeObj.newobject()

rec = recordTypeObj.newobject()
rec.ID = 1
rec.NAME = "foo"
tab.append(rec)

rec = recordTypeObj.newobject()
rec.ID = 2
rec.NAME = "bar"
tab.append(rec)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.callproc("test.foo", [tab])
```

Comment: In [the release notes for 5.3](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes.html) it says `Added support for creating, modifying and binding PL/SQL records and collections (available in Oracle 12.1).` Would you know if this is the note that you are referring to, and whether or not this implies that it won't work on 11g?

Comment: Yes. This is not supported in Oracle 11g.

Comment: `conn.gettype('TEST.R_FOO')` is throwing a `DatabaseError: ORA-04043: object test.r_foo does not exist`. It appears that cx_Oracle isn't finding any types within a package; whereas it can find a type outside of a package. Would you mind taking a look at my updated question?

Comment: That suggests you are using Oracle 11g, which is not supported. Are you using 12c client and server?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I was on 11G, but I have now upgraded to 12CR1, yet I'm still receiving the same error. The output of `cx_Oracle.version` is `5.3` and the output of `cx_Oracle.clientversion()` is `(12, 1, 0, 2, 0)`. Any idea as to why it's not working?

Comment: Please provide the code you are using -- both SQL and Python -- and the output you are receiving. cx_Oracle 5.3 and higher with Oracle 12.1 do support records and collections (not table indexed by varchar2, though!).

Comment: Hey Anthony, I have updated my post to include the full code, at the bottom. Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Thanks. That code still works for me. Not sure why you are experiencing difficulties. May I suggest you try cx_Oracle 6.0rc1 -- which has even better support for Oracle objects like the ones you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I think I may have solved the issue by simply uninstalling/reinstalling cx_Oracle... I believe the problem is that when I originally installed cx_Oracle, it was when my ORACLE_HOME and etc environment variables were pointed to an 11G instance. Then after upgrading my DB to 12C, I had assumed that simply changing the ORACLE_HOME/etc to my 12C client libraries would have been sufficient.

Comment: I can replicate this by `pip uninstall cx_Oracle`, `set ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/11g/home/`, `pip install cx_Oracle --no-cache`, `set ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/12c/home/` `python -c "import cx_Oracle; conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("cx_Oracle/dev@localhost/orcl"); conn.gettype('TEST.R_FOO')"`

Comment: You can also get this if your database is 11.2. You must have both client and database at 12.1 or higher before this code will work.